# Spring Cloud without Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

Can you please provide any sample code / steps to connect to Spring Cloud - GIT without Spring Boot?

I need to connect to Spring Cloud through GITLAB without spring boot.

Comment: Are you talking about config server? is there an existing one? Are you looking for an http api? https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#_quick_start

Comment: Yes, there's an existing GIT repository. I need to read the property files from the existing git repository through Spring Cloud... I have already implemented the same through Spring Cloud using Spring Boot, but I have to implement this Spring Cloud without Spring boot. Please assist on the same.. Thanks

Comment: Did you look at the docs I linked to?

Comment: They have apis or paths that any application can call